# Open AI localhost isn't working, error http 429 appears

Tags: node.js, .net, openai-api, dotenv

I'm planning to create an open ai application with its own api. So I watched some videos how to code an own app, with client-side and server-side scripts and tried to run the projects in vs code in seperate terminals. Everything seemed to look fine, but I get an http 429 error. I found out that my programme is sending too many messages to the server at once. I'm like not a advanced programmer, therefore I have no clue how I should continue. Is there any possibility that it is linked to the fact, that I'm not paying for an API_KEY, that I declared in my programme earlier? So that there is like one request to the server, but he doesn't respond, because I have no tokens or things like that? I thought it would be for free when using it local. FYI, I coded in node.js, express and dotenv if that helps you in any way. Let me know if you need the script. Thanks yall and have a nice day :)

I tried to see what Open AI is writing to its usage as a library but couldnt find anything